# Are GET request header fields and values case-sensitive?

Tags: c, header, get

I'm working on a programing assignment regarding using GET request.
I am using C.

I wonder if any headers fields and values of GET packet have to be capitalized?

For example:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

vs

```
get / HTTP/1.1
connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP method names are [case-sensitive](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.1):

> The Method token indicates the method
>   to be performed on the resource
>   identified by the Request-URI. The
>   method is *case-sensitive*.

HTTP header names are [case-insensitive](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2).

Comment: The RFC seems to be silent on the case-sensitivity of field *values*.

Comment: @Martin probably because each header type can impose its own rules.

Comment: @Martin: in general certainly they have to be case-sensitive, since for example the `Location` header field can contain a URL. It would be a bit of a problem if a proxy server down-cased it!